# ¿Por qué no migrar las preguntas en ingles directamente a SO inglés?

Tags: discusión

Veo que las preguntas en inglés no son muchas, pero si esto crece se va a ser más complicado el tema. Además veo que las preguntas en inglés son directamente cerradas. ¿No corresponderia migrarlas al sitio en inglés?

A veces no sabemos si el usuario habla español (ayer alguien tradujo una pregunta, OP nunca apareció hasta donde había visto) y hoy apareció otra en inglés, donde OP no parece saber español (es más, tiene nombre oriental).

No sería pertinente, antes que cerrarlas, migrarlas porque pertenecen allá. Y así también ayudar a OP a saber dónde tiene que preguntar, en lugar de rechazarlos de plano.

Comment: Yo pienso que es mejor dejarlo tal cual, ya que generalmente se les hace un comentario que la pregunta debe ser en español, también siempre hay un usuario que le hace la misma sugerencia en inglés. En caso no edita su pregunta aún después de las sugerencias ya cierran esa pregunta o en caso la edite al español la reabren. Si se aplica tu idea de migrar esa pregunta directamente se corre el riesgo que el op si hable español y solo se haya equivocado.

Comment: Si habla español volvera. si no por lo menos su pregunta quedara resuelta. Asi estamos directamente cerrando preguntas (correctamente) que tal vez podrian ser salvadas. Si OP habla español y prefiere ese idioma, volvera.

Comment: 1. Se necesitan varios supuestos para traducir una pregunta. No es conveniente suponer o adivinar. 2. Si esto crece, el número de revisores potenciales también crece.

Comment: Algo debería hacerse, sí. Respondí con más detalles. Por otra parte, intenta tener más a mano las tildes ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Sugiero que se enseñe un mensajito automático cuando se detecte que la publicación está escrita en inglés. Lo bueno es que la tecnología para hacerlo ya existe:

En Stack Overflow en inglés están realizando un experimento para estimar cuántas preguntas se escriben en idiomas que tienen sitio propio. En concreto, para portugués y castellano.

En caso que exista alguna de estas palabras (sacado de [False Positive Spanish Language Detection when Asking Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/325866/1983854)):

> UN|CON|CÓMO|UNA|EL|AL|PUEDO|DATOS|COMO|DESDE|HACER|QUÉ|DEL|MI

o caracteres:

> áéíóúüñ¿¡

Aparece este mensajito:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por si no se ve bien, copio lo que dice:

> Si quieres preguntar en español, lo puedes hacer aquí: [Stack Overfow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?utm_source=soen-es).

<sub>El enlace envía a `https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?utm_source=soen-es` exactamente, por lo que entiendo que usan la parte de `utm_source` para hacer las estadísticas.</sub>

Dado que la tecnología existe y la forma de hacer actual es bastante manejable (parece que no hay una carga de machine learning, sino solamente expresiones regulares), podría implementarse también en Stack Overflow en español con palabras comunes del tipo *how*, *what* y demás.